# How to run Fastlane pipeline for feature branches?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, fastlane

This is what I define in `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
build:

  stage: build

  script:
    - bundle exec pod repo update
    - bundle exec pod install || bundle exec pod install --repo-update
    - bundle exec fastlane build

  when: always

  only:
    - feature/* #when I change this to - feature/swd/fastlane then it works.

  tags:
    - iOS
```

but this doesn't work.

The following branches should start the pipeline:

`feature/swd/fastlane`, `feature/swd/245`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a regex for `only` you need use delimiters ([Sample in documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified)).

So you have to write:

```
only:
  - /feature\/*/
```

Where `/` at the beginning and at the end are used as delimiters and the path separator `/` needs to be escaped with a back slash `\`.